# Can "and" as conjunction connect two different part of speech?

Tags: conjunctions, parts-of-speech

> **You can enjoy the wonderful view over the old commercial and banking center of the city.**

I think here "and" connects "commercial" and "banking".

By looking up the dictionary, [commercial](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/commercial_1) should be an adjective ([usually before noun ]connected with the buying and selling of goods and services); [banking](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/banking) is a noun (the business activity of banks).

Or are you saying "commercial" means advertisement, a noun?

So can a conjunction connect two different part of speech?

If so, is "**He is tall and Tom**" natural? Can you give some examples?

Comment: _Banking_ acts like an adjective here, describing the part of the city where banking takes place.

Comment: @KateBunting So it's like  _chocolate milk_, where chocolate is noun in dictionary, but describes the second noun like an adjective? Then how about "He is tall and Tom"?

Comment: "He is tall and Tom" doesn't work.  But in your original sentence, both *commercial* and *banking* work like adjectives, like in "He is tall and thin."

Comment: And yes, nouns can be used like adjectives to modify another noun.   (e.g. chocolate milk, horse race, chicken soup, car door, etc.)

Comment: In coordinative structures, it's generally not the parts of speech that are important but their function. "Commercial" and "banking" both modify "centre" so there's no problem. Importantly, each coordinate could occur alone with the same function: 
" ... view over the old commercial center of the city" /  "... view over the old banking center of the city".

Comment: Although tall and Tom have different part of speech, why can't they both work like adjectives? Because "He is tall" and "He is Tom" are both natural.

Comment: I can't imagine any circumstances in which a person would say 'He is tall and Tom'. You don't describe a person and then identify them like that; you would say either 'The tall man is called Tom' or 'Tom is tall'.

Comment: @Gqqnbig They are both modifiers. "He is tall and Tom" is semantically very odd, but grammatically OK.